# Groovy/Grails code cleanup suggestions, please!

Tags: grails, groovy, coding-style

I'm new to Groovy & Grails, and I have a feeling that things don't have to be this ugly... so how can I make this code nicer?

This is a Grails controller class, minus some uninteresting bits.  Try not to get too hung up that my `Car` only has one `Wheel` - I can deal with that later :-)

`changeWheel` is an Ajax action.

```
class MyController {
    ...
    def changeWheel = {
        if(params['wheelId']) {
            def newWheel = Wheel.findById(params['wheelId'])
            if(newWheel) {
                def car = Car.findById(params['carId'])
                car?.setWheel(newWheel)
                if(car?.save()) render 'OK'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd actually start using [Command Objects](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.10%20Command%20Objects).

Try this:

```
class MyController {
    def index = {
    }
    def changeWheel = { CarWheelCommand cmd ->
        if(cmd.wheel && cmd.car) {
            Car car = cmd.car
            car.wheel = cmd.wheel
            render car.save() ? 'OK' : 'ERROR'
        } else {
            render "Please enter a valid Car and wheel id to change"
        }
    }
}
class CarWheelCommand {
    Car car
    Wheel wheel
}
```

and then in your view use '`car.id`' and '`wheel.id`' instead of '`carId`' and '`wheelId`'

Comment: The Command object will automatically do the GORM stuff required to fetch a Car/Wheel?  I don't think that's true and that somewhere in his code he'd still have to have Wheel.findById(cmd.wheel.id) and Car.findById(cmd.car.id).

Comment: Here is a working example: https://github.com/ColinHarrington/CommandObjectExample (grails 1.3.5)

Comment: Thanks for the example, I didn't expect it would work like that (ah the magic of Grails).  In your example you could also add constraints for car and wheel of nullable:false then use if(cmd.validate()).

Comment: When a command is passed into the controller it is already validated, so you don't need to call validate again.  Also because Car has a Wheel, that implicitly has a nullable constraint on it.

Comment: Got it, so "if(!cmd.hasErrors())" would be more appropriate. I do think that if(!cmd.hasErrors()) or if(cmd.validate()) would look cleaner than if(cmd.wheel && cmd.car) as a way to validate the input to changeWheel.

Comment: cripes @colin, that's cunning!  How do the Car and Wheel get into the Command?  Would it be possible for the command object to pick up the Wheel if it's specified by something other than `wheel.id`, e.g. `wheel.description`?  What if I defined two different Wheels?  (or just tell me to go read up about CommandObjects and ask another question when I've got my head round them, if that's more suitable).

Comment: @colin.  thats is pretty cool.  so to confirm, the command will in fact load the objects for you?  How far back in the grails versions is that available?  The only thing I don't about it is that for the most part, loading/saving should be in a service.  But I took the question to be more about cleaning up the code, not architecting the software.

Comment: @Alison It basically does Data Binding on the Command Object http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.6%20Data%20Binding

Comment: @Alison You could also read up on bindData() http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/bindData.html

Answer (score 3):

1)  pull

```
params['wheelId']
```

and

```
params['carId']
```

out into their own defs

2)  multiple nested ifs is never optimal.  You can get rid of the outermost one by having a validateParams method and rendering some sort of response if wheelId and carId are not set.  Or just do

```
if (carId == null || wheelId == null) {
    // params invalid
}
```

3) Assuming everything is ok you could just do

```
def newWheel = Wheel.findById...
def car = Car.findById...
if (car != null && newWheel != null) {
    car.setWheel(newWheel)
    car.save()
    render 'OK'
} else {
   // either wheel or car is null

}
```

this gets rid of more nested structures...

4) finally, to make the code self documenting, you can do things like assign the conditional tests to appropriately named variables.  So something like

```
def carAndWheelOk = car != null && newWheel != null
if (carAndWheelOk) {
   // do the save
} else {
   // car or wheel not ok
}
```

this might be overkill for two tests, but  you only are taking care of one wheel here. If you were dealing with all 4 wheels, this type of things increases readability and maintainability.

Note that this advice works in any language.  I don't think you can do too much with groovy's syntactic sugar, but maybe some groovy gurus can offer better advice.

Comment: heh, thanks for the rest :-)  de-nesting definitely looks good; i'm hoping also for a Groovy guru to suggest I replace the whole thing with a magic closure.  BTW in your answer you're ignoring `save()` failing.

Comment: @alison, you will notice that in controllers, you define closures, and in services, you define methods.  so you already have a closure.

Comment: Yep.  Is it bad practice to create methods in a Controller then?  e.g. a private method `getCarFromParams()`

Comment: @alison, no, utility methods are fine.  The actions that get invoked should be closures though.

Comment: Why do null checks when you could use the Groovy Truth? ie: if (car && wheel) { ... }

Comment: @colin  yes you can do that; i prefer to be as explicit as possible so that my intent is always as clear as possible to those who come after me.

Comment: @hvgotcodes i definitely get where you're coming from on this, coming from Java, but @colin is it 'Groovier' to just check `if(car && wheel)`?  I'm guessing if this is standard practice in Groovy, then the intent should be clear.

Comment: @alison,  you can certainly do it that way.  Its not even a groovy thing; lots of languages have 'truthy' and 'falsy'.   I look forward to the SO questions around 'why is this expression evaluating to true?' :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things you could do like move some code to a service or command object.  But without altering the structure too much, I (subjectively) think the following would make the code easier to read:

1. use dot notation instead of array indexing to reference params values (params.wheelId instead of params['wheelId'])
2. I would invert the if to reduce nesting, I think this makes it more clear what the exceptions are.

For example:

```
if(!params.wheelId) {
    sendError(400, "wheelId is required")
    return
}
....
....
if(!newWheel) {
    sendError(404, "wheel ${params.wheelId} was not found.")
    return
}
```

Now if you don't mind changing the structure and adding more lines of code...

The act of changing the wheel may be a common occurrence across more than just one controller action.  In this case I'd recommend putting the GORM/database logic in a Service class.  Then your controller only has to verify it has the correct **params** inputs and pass those on to the Service to do the actual tire changing. A Service method can be transactional, which you'd want in the case where you might have to dismount the old tire before mounting the new one.

In the Service I would throw exceptions for exceptional cases like when a wheel is not found, a car is not found, or if there's an error changing the tire.  Then your controller can catch those and respond with the proper HTTP status codes.